# Combining ConversationalRetrievalQAChain and APIChain using Tools and Agents

Tags: node.js, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, openai-api, langchain

I created a vector store and I was successfully able to do questioning and answering using `ConversationalRetrievalQAChain`.
I wanted to add an ability where I can make an API call, For that I used API Chain. Both the chains were working fine individually. I was thinking to combine them. After digging through the `Langchain`'s documentation I came to know that this scenario can be achieved using tools and agents in such a manner that it will decide what chain to use based on the user's question(input).

Below are some key concepts from my implementation:

- **`ConversationalRetrievalQAChain` and `APIChain` configuration**

```js
const qaChain = ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(
  new OpenAI({
    modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    streaming: true,
    verbose: true,
    temperature: 0,
  }),
  vectorStore.asRetriever(1),
  {
    returnSourceDocuments: true, //default 4
    qaChainOptions: {
      type: 'stuff',
      prompt: new PromptTemplate({
        template: QA_TEMPLATE,
        inputVariables: ["question", "context"]
      })
    },
    questionGeneratorChainOptions: {
      llm: new ChatOpenAI({
        modelName: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        verbose: true,
        temperature: 0,
      }),
      template: QUESTION_TEMPLATE
    },
  }
);

const apiChain = APIChain.fromLLMAndAPIDocs(model, OPEN_METEO_DOCS);
```

- **Tools configuration:**

```js
const qaChainTool = new ChainTool({
  name: "qa",
  description: "useful for when you need to ask questions.",
  chain: qaChain,
});

const apiChainTool = new ChainTool({
  name: "weather-api",
  description: "Request - useful for when you need to ask questions about weather of a city.",
  chain: apiChain,
});
```

- **Agent configuration:**

```js
const tools = [apiChainTool, qaChainTool]

const executor = await initializeAgentExecutorWithOptions(tools, model, {
  agentType: 'chat-conversational-react-description',
  verbose: true
});

const res = await executor.call({ input: < user_input > });

console.log(res);
```

**Problem/Issue:** When the executor(agent) is called with the user's input it does not provide the proper response for both weather and general questioning and answering.

**Observation:** When this same scenario is run using `RetrievalQAChain` and `APIChain` then it works totally fine and as expected. The problem persists when combining `ConversationalRetrievalQAChain` with `APIChain`.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks